# Esseen's inequality for random series?

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

I am reading about convergence rates in the central limit theorem and have a question regarding Esseen's inequality.

Suppose $(X_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an independent sequence of random variables such that $\mathbb{E}X_j=0$ and $\mathbb{E}\lvert X_j\rvert^3<\infty$ for $j\in\mathbb{N}$. Define $\sigma^2_j:=\mathbb{E}X_j^2$ for $j\in\mathbb{N}$. As a reminder:

**Esseen's inequality:**. Let $n \in\mathbb{N}$. Put $B_n:=\sum_{j=1}^n\sigma_j^2$ and $F_n(x):=\mathbb{P}\left(B_n^{-1/2}\sum_{j=1}^n X_j<x\right)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then for some absolute constant $c$
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left\lvert F_n(x)-\Phi(x)\right\rvert \leq cB_n^{-3/2}\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}\lvert X_j\rvert^3 \tag{1},$$
where $\Phi$ denotes the cdf of the standard normal distribution.

Is then also the following true (with or without additional assumptions)?

**Esseen's inequality for random series:** Assume additionally that all the (random) series in the following converge and put $F(x):=\mathbb{P}\left(\left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sigma_j^2\right)^{-1/2}\sum_{j=1}^\infty X_j<x\right)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, 
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left\lvert F(x)-\Phi(x)\right\rvert \leq c\left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sigma_j^2\right)^{-3/2}\sum_{j=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}\lvert X_j\rvert^3,$$ where $c$ is the same constant as above.

Do we need that $F_n$ converges uniformly to $\Phi$, in order to interchange the limit and supremem on the LHS, when taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ in (1)?

EDIT: To clarify, I am additionally assuming  here that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sigma_j^2<\infty$, $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}\lvert X_j\rvert^3<\infty$, and the random series $\sum_{j=1}^\infty X_j$ converges almost surely.

Comment: Caution: $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \mathbb E|X_j|^3$ and $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \sigma_j^2$ might diverge (e.g take $\sigma_j = \mathbb E|X_j|^3 = 1$ for all $j$), and so your conjecture wouldn't even make sense to begin with.

Comment: I am aware of that. That's why I had put in the additional assumption that all series in the statement converge.

Comment: I edited the question to make the additional assumption clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a positive $\varepsilon$ and let $A_n$ be the event 
$$
A_n:=\left\{\left\lvert \left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sigma_j^2\right)^{-1/2}\sum_{j=1}^\infty X_j-B_n^{-1/2}\sum_{j=1}^n X_j \right\rvert \gt \varepsilon\right\}.$$
Then for all $x\in\mathbb R$,
$$
F(x)-\Phi(x)\leqslant \mathbb{P}\left(\left(\left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sigma_j^2\right)^{-1/2}\sum_{j=1}^\infty X_j<x\right)\cap A_n^c\right)+\mathbb P(A_n)-\Phi(x)
$$
and the inclusion 
$$
\left\{ \left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sigma_j^2\right)^{-1/2}\sum_{j=1}^\infty X_j<x\right\}\cap A_n^c \subset \left\{B_n^{-1/2}\sum_{j=1}^n X_j<x+\varepsilon \right\}
$$
hold hence 
$$
F(x)-\Phi(x)\leqslant F_n(x+\varepsilon)-\Phi(x+\varepsilon)+
\Phi(x+\varepsilon)-\Phi(x)+\mathbb P(A_n).$$
Thus, Esseen's inequality gives that for all $n$, 
$$
F(x)-\Phi(x)\leqslant cB_n^{-3/2}\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}\lvert X_j\rvert^3+
\sup_{x\in\mathbb R} \left(\Phi(x+\varepsilon)-\Phi(x)\right)+\mathbb P(A_n)
$$
and letting $n$ going to infinity gives 
$$
F(x)-\Phi(x)\leqslant c\left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sigma_j^2\right)^{-3/2}\sum_{j=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}\lvert X_j\rvert^3+
\sup_{x\in\mathbb R} \left(\Phi(x+\varepsilon)-\Phi(x)\right) .
$$
The later supremum is reached for $x=-\varepsilon/2$ and is $\mathbb P\left(-\varepsilon/2\leqslant N\leqslant \varepsilon/2\right)$, where $N$ has a standard normal distribution and this goes to $0$ as $\varepsilon$ goes to $0$.

It remains to find an upper bound for $\Phi(x)-F(x)$. Here again, intersect with $A_n$ and  control the difference between $F(x)$ and $F_n(x-\varepsilon)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!